# How could I display the category orderly in left outer join in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-order-by

How could I display this query, ordered by qid?

```
  $newcount=$db->get_results("
        SELECT  s2.qcategory, 
                s1.id, 
                count(s1.na) as na_count 
        FROM    (
                    select  distinct `qcategory` 
                    from    store 
                    where   survey_name='$userID' and 
                            dateone='$dateVal' and 
                            branch='$branch'
                ) s2 
                left join store s1 
                    on s1.`qcategory` = s2.`qcategory` and 
                        s1.`na` = '1' 
        group by 1 
        order by s1.qid");
```

Comment: Any error you are getting???

Comment: you may just need to include qid in the selected values

Comment: @Rhumborl not needed to include, it will still sort even without it on the select clause..

Comment: @JW. ok havent done mysql for a while, couldn't remember

Comment: @SashiKant No i want to display this value as qid order it wont displayed it so

Comment: @UjwalKoirala what is the data type of `qid`?

Comment: @JW I tried it it wont work.

Comment: @UjwalKoirala what did you try? I am asking for the data type `:D`

Comment: @JW Data type is Varchar

Comment: @UjwalKoirala that the reason why it wont be sorted, you need to convert it to numeric first, see my answer below to know how.

Comment: @JW. AFAIK, `VARCHAR` can be sorted.

Comment: @TheDOCTORfromTARDIS No, [CLICK HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ed0/2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since the data type is `VARCHAR` you need to convert it to numeric, eg

```
ORDER BY CAST(s1.qid AS SIGNED) ASC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ed0/2)

Comment: It wornt display the category orderly

Comment: @UjwalKoirala add another column, `ORDER BY CAST(s1.qid AS SIGNED) ASC, s2.qcategory ASC` is *s2.qcategory* still varchar?

Comment: yes qcategory contans categories like "First Impression", "Staff Professional Image", "Quality And Valu" etc I want to display this value in qid order

Comment: can you add sample records with desired result? it will be so much useful.

Comment: I already add these values in database but while extracting it wont display as qid actually i am trying to pass one loop value to another but its make me quit trouble can you please give some idea

Comment: $newcount=$db->get_results("SELECT s2.qcategory, s1.id, count(s1.na) as na_count FROM (select distinct `qcategory` from store where survey_name='$userID' and dateone='$dateVal' and branch='$branch' ORDER BY CAST(aid AS SIGNED) asc ) s2  left join store s1  on  s1.`qcategory` = s2.`qcategory` and s1.`na` = '1' group by qcategory  ORDER BY s1.qid  desc  " );
 
 
 foreach($newcount as $sqcount)
 {
 
 echo "<p align=right>". $sqcount->qcategory;
 echo "<br>".$sqcount->na_count;
 $arval[$j]=$sqcount->na_count;
//echo  $arval[$j];
 echo "</p>";
 
 
 $j++;

Comment: $newqcat=$db->get_results("SELECT count(id) as r_count, sum(point) as point_value,dateone, na, qcategory FROM store where survey_name like '%$userID%' and dateone='$dateVal' and branch='$branch' group by qcategory");
 if($newqcat)
 {
 foreach($newqcat as $sqcat1)
   {
$vv1=$arval[$i];
  $tcount_val1=$sqcat1->r_count-$vv1;
$per=($sqcat1->point_value*100)/($tcount_val1*5);
}

Comment: no, try to move the order into the outer query, eg `SELECT .... FROM (subquery) left join ...... ORDER BY CAST(aid AS SIGNED) asc`

Comment: it wont I just tried the same order by work in 2nd query but in this query SELECT .... FROM (subquery) left join ...... ORDER BY CAST(aid AS SIGNED) asc it wont work

Answer (score 1):

u maybe want to order ASC or DESC

try this

```
     ORDER BY s1.qid  ASC
```

or

```
   ORDER BY s1.qid  DESC
```

and why you make `GROUP BY 1` ??

Comment: these two: `AND s1.na = '1'` and `AND s1.na = 1` are the same. MySQL automatically cast it for you.

Comment: @JW na means not applicable value and its count each category if na =1